# EditText not deleting text on BACKSPACE in Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a UI component that extends EditText. It watches for changes to text contents by the user with a TextWatcher.

I have a problem that only shows in Android 4.1.2:
My component (previously) selects a range of text selected programatically, using setSelection() to set start of selection and extendSelection() to extend it.

When the text is selected, the beforeTextChanged() and afterTextChanged(0 are NOT called when backspace is typed.

Entering a character at the keyboard causes the selected text range to be replaced with the type character correctly, so it appears the selection is working.

This works fine in Android 4.0.2 and other versions I have tried.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the workaround I found is in the manifest, set targetSdk = 15 or lower.